# Which wildcard in SQL-Statement do I have to use for an Access *.mdb-file query (using Java & JDBC:ODBC bridge)

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I try to execute the following SQL-Statement (in my Java-application):

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Job WHERE jobname LIKE '%aa%';
```

But I can't get the same (correct?) result using MS Access (2002):

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Job WHERE jobname LIKE '*aa*';
```

With this example Access will give me 400 datasets and my Java-application will only give me somewhat less I don't know the exact number of datasets.

I tried to use the [*]-wildcard in my Java-app but it didn't give me any datasets at all.
Besides I tried to replace the [']-character with the ["]-character but this didn't work either.

I don't know whether this is relevant or not but I think the *.mdb-file was created with MS Access (2000)

My Java code:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:_
                        Driver={Microsoft Access Driver_
                        (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\database.mdb");
Statement stm = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
    do_some_stuff();
```

Comment: I have seen a number of posts in forums that suggest that different results can be obtained with OleDB and ODBC. One suggestion was that listing fields rather than using * might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest you try this SQL statement both from Java and directly in Access.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS num_rows FROM Tbl_Job WHERE jobname ALike '%aa%';
```

If `num_rows` is the same in both cases, change the WHERE clause in your first query to match this one.

If `num_rows` is not the same in both cases, please describe how they differ and which is correct.

Comment: Using Alike instead of like does the trick! Thank you very much! :D